# Como arreglo este codigo

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un space invaders en java y necesito ayuda. Mi problema es que las naves alieningenas solo bajan en vez de bajar y cambiar de direccion.
Os dejo mi codigo. Ademas de que se salen del tablero. Agradeceria la ayuda

Alien Manager.java:

```
import tp1.logic.gameobjects.RegularAlien;
//import tp1.logic.gameobjects.DestroyerAlien;

//import tp1.logic.lists.DestroyerAlienList;
import tp1.logic.lists.RegularAlienList;

/**
 * 
 * Manages alien initialization and
 * used by aliens to coordinate movement
 *
 */
public class AlienManager {
    
    private Level level;
    private Game game;
    private int remainingAliens;
    
    private boolean squadInFinalRow = false;
    private int shipsOnBorder = 0;
    private boolean onBorder = false;
    private RegularAlienList list;
    
    public AlienManager(Game game, Level level, RegularAlienList list) {
        this.level = level;
        this.game = game;
        this.remainingAliens = 5;
        this.list = list;
        
    }
        
    // INITIALIZER METHODS
    
    /**
     * Initializes the list of regular aliens
     * @return the initial list of regular aliens according to the current level
     */
    protected RegularAlienList initializeRegularAliens() {
        list = new RegularAlienList(level.getNumRegularAliens());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Position alienPosition = new Position(i + 2, 3);
            RegularAlien alien = new RegularAlien(game, this, alienPosition);
            list.add(alien);}
        return list;
    }


    /**
     * Initializes the list of destroyer aliens
     * @return the initial list of destroyer aliens according to the current level
     */
//  protected  DestroyerAlienList initializeDestroyerAliens() {
//   for (int i = 0; i < level.getDestroyerAlienCount(); i++) {
//       DestroyerAlien destroyerAlien = new DestroyerAlien(/* pass the appropriate arguments */);
//       destroyerAlienList.add(destroyerAlien);
//  }
    
    public int getRemainingAliens() {
        return this.remainingAliens;
    }
    
    public boolean allAlienDead() {
        return getRemainingAliens() == 0;
    }
    
    public boolean alienDead() {
        boolean dead = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             RegularAlien alien = list.getObjectInPosition(i);
             if(!alien.isAlive()) {
                 this.remainingAliens--;
                 dead = true;
             }
        }
        return dead;
    }
    
    public boolean haveLanded() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean finalRowReached() {
        boolean finalRow = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             RegularAlien alien = list.getObjectInPosition(i);
             if(alien.isinFinalRow()) {
                 finalRow = true;
             }  
        }
        return finalRow;
    }
```

Devuelve true si estan listos los aliens

```
public boolean readyToDescent() {
                boolean desc = false;
                if (isInBorder()) {
                    if (!onBorder) {
                        onBorder = true;
                    } else {
                        decreaseOnBorder();
                        desc = true;
                        onBorder = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    onBorder = false;
                }
                return desc;
            }
        
            
            public void decreaseOnBorder() {
                for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                     RegularAlien alien = list.getObjectInPosition(i);
                     alien.descent();
                }
            }
            
            // CONTROL METHODS
```

Deuveluve true si hay aliens en el borde

```
public boolean shipOnBorder() {
                boolean esBor = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && !esBor; i++) {
                     RegularAlien alien = list.getObjectInPosition(i);
                     Position position = alien.getPosition();
                    if (position.getX() == 0 || position.getX() == Game.DIM_X-1) {
                       esBor = true;
                    }
                }
                return esBor;
            }
        
            public boolean isInBorder() {
                boolean esBorde = false;
                if(shipOnBorder()) {
                    esBorde = true;
                    onBorder = true;
                }
                return esBorde;
            }
        
        }
```

y mi codigo de Regular Alien.java

```
package tp1.logic.gameobjects;
    
    import tp1.logic.AlienManager;
    import tp1.logic.Game;
    import tp1.logic.Move;
    import tp1.logic.Position;
    import tp1.view.Messages;
    
    /**
     * Class representing a regular alien
     */
    public class RegularAlien {
    
        public int armor = 2;
        public Position pos;
        public int life;
        public Game game;
        public Move dir;
        public int cyclesToMove;
        public int speed;
        public AlienManager alienManager;
        private boolean onBorder = false;
     
        
        public RegularAlien(Game game, AlienManager manager, Position pos) {
            this.life = armor;
            this.pos = pos;
            this.game = game;
            this.dir = Move.LEFT;
            this.cyclesToMove = 4;
            this.speed = 1;
            this.alienManager = manager;
        }
    
        public boolean isAlive() {
            return getLife() > 0;
        }
    
        public int getLife() {
            return life;
        }
    
        public void die() {
            life = 0;
        }

    public boolean isOnPosition(Position position) {
        return (this.pos.getX() == position.getX()) && (this.pos.getY() == position.getY());
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void receiveDamage() {
        life -= getDamage();
    }

    public boolean isOut() {
        return pos.getY() < 0  || pos.getX() < 0 || pos.getX() >= Game.DIM_X; 
    }

    public boolean isinFinalRow() {
        return pos.getY() >= Game.DIM_Y; 
    }

    private void performMovement(Move dir) {
        
        pos = new Position(pos.getX() + dir.getX(), pos.getY() + dir.getY());
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return Messages.REGULAR_ALIEN_SYMBOL + "[" + life + "]";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getDescription()+ ":" + getInfo();
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return Messages.ALIEN_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Messages.REGULAR_ALIEN_DESCRIPTION ; 
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return 1; 
    }

    public void computerAction() {
      
    }

    public void onDelete() {
        die();
    }
    
    public void automaticMove() {
        cyclesToMove--;
        if (cyclesToMove == 0) {
            performMovement(dir);
            cyclesToMove = 4; 
        }
    }
    
    public void descent() {
        performMovement(Move.DOWN);
            if (dir == Move.RIGHT) {
                dir = Move.LEFT;
            } else {
                dir = Move.RIGHT;
            }
  
    }
    
    public boolean isInBorder() {
        return pos.getX() == 0 || pos.getX() >= Game.DIM_X - 1;
    }

    public boolean receiveAttack(UCMLaser laser) {
        if (pos.equals(laser.pos)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
}
```